# PHP - PDO Mysql not found! php_mysql.so exists, but phpinfo only shows sqlite

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I installed different php versions on my Debian server for some reasons (Php **5.3.10**, 5.4.41, 5.5.25, 5.6.9 and 7.0.17). I installed them from source.

I'm trying to get the mysql php pdo to work with **php 5.3.10**. 
The active version on Debian is 5.4.41. and **php5-mysql** is installed by

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

When I check php info in the console or by `phpinfo();` for php 5.4.41 the result is:

```
~$ php --info | grep pdo
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
pdo_mysql
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

But result of phpinfo() in another vHost that works with php 5.3.10 is:

[image]
and

[image]

and

[image]

Even I uncomment *.so files in php.ini

```
extension=mysql.so
extension=pdo.so
```

But no pdo_mysql.so being loaded!

Extra info:
OS: Debian 7.8
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini` is only for cli. You need to add a similar symlink for the web server to. If you're running Apache, the symlink should be in `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/` folder

Comment: @magnus-eriksson I manually installed PHP (./configure make make install) and I can not find apache2 folder like `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/`. If I make this manually, does it work?

Comment: Actually, now I see that you have `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d` in your phpinfo() under "Scan this dir for additional .ini files" so it should actually pick that up. If you run `php -m` in the terminal, do you see `pdo_mysql` in that list? Also, what does the file `20-pdo_mysql.ini` actually contain?

Comment: Btw, did you restart the Apache server after making changes? That's important for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Yes I see `pdo_mysql` with command `php -m`. the file `20-pdo_mysql.ini` contains `extension=mysql.so`. Yes I restarted several times after each change. And when I run `php -v` result is `php 5.4.45`!